# Existence of a particular element of an ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, filters

I'm getting to know some ultrafilter theory. I'm stuck on the following exercise:

Suppose $ \mathcal{U} $ is an ultrafilter on $ \omega $. Prove that there exists $ A \in \mathcal{U} $ such that
$$\liminf\limits_{n < \omega}\frac{|A \cap n|}{n} = 0$$

I'm not sure how to approach this and to interpret the limit.

I would appreciate a hint

Comment: Just in case, $|A\cap n|$ is the cardinal of $A\cap\{0,\dots,n-1\}$. So you have a sequence and you compute its [limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences) $\lim\inf$ for some $A$.

Answer (score 5):

$|A \cap n|$ is just the intersection of $A$ with $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$. $\lim \inf$ is the smallest of all accumulation points of a given sequence. Thus, to prove that $$\liminf\limits_{n < \omega}\frac{|A \cap n|}{n} = 0$$
As the sequence has all non-negative terms, it's enough to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ such that $\frac{|A \cap n|}{n} < \epsilon$.

The way I would approach it is to exhibit a set $X$ such that satisfies 
$$\liminf\limits_{n < \omega}\frac{|X \cap n|}{n} = 0,\quad \liminf\limits_{n < \omega}\frac{|(\mathbb{N}-X) \cap n|}{n} = 0$$
Now at least one of $X, \mathbb{N}-X$ must belong to the ultrafilter.

Comment: An additional hint: You can construct $X$ by carefully adding long sequence $\{k, k+1, \ldots, k+l\}$ to $X$ that are followed by longer sequences $\{k+l, k+l+1, \ldots, k+l+m \}$ in $\omega \setminus X$ that are followed by even longer...